# HttpConnectionManagerParams not working for HTTPS URL

Tags: java, apache-camel, java-ee-6, camel-http

We use Apache Camel's **camel-http** component to integrate with HTTP endpoints, **HttpConnectionManagerParams** is used to configure defaultconnectionsPerHost and maxTotalConnections.

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpConnectionManagerParams" id="MyHttpConnectionManagerParams">
    <property name="defaultMaxConnectionsPerHost" value="20"/>
    <property name="maxTotalConnections" value="200"/>
</bean>
```

Above parameters takes effect only if the endpoint URL is over HTTP, same configuration becomes void and default **HttpConnectionManager** takes effect when endpoint is over HTTPS.

Is there something to be additionally configured for HTTPS url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding below beans has solved works for me.
Agreed there is no component named HTTPS in Camel but things are working with below configuration both in older and newer versions of Apache Camel.

```
<bean class="org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpComponent" id="http">
   <property name="camelContext" ref="myCamelContext"/>
   <property name="httpConnectionManager" ref="MyHttpConnectionManager"/>
 </bean>
<bean class="org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpComponent" id="https">
   <property name="camelContext" ref="myCamelContext"/>
   <property name="httpConnectionManager" ref="MyHttpConnectionManager"/>
 </bean>
<bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager" id="MyHttpConnectionManager">
   <property name="params" ref="MyHttpConnectionManagerParams"/>
 </bean>
<bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpConnectionManagerParams" id="MyHttpConnectionManagerParams">
   <property name="defaultMaxConnectionsPerHost" value="100"/>
   <property name="maxTotalConnections" value="500"/>
 </bean>
```